# Add link that performs database function

Tags: forms

I am building a tableselect. What I want is to have last row be a link that when clicked performs a CRUD using the row ID as input. The goal is to have a "delete" link that removes that row from the database. Or an add link that does the reverse.

I am looking at the example of the admin/content, which creates links like I need at the end of its table. But because this works on Nodes and I am working on database rows (in a custom table), this doesn't seem to really apply.

Are there any good tutorials/examples on something like this. I've found a few that helped me create the table, but this functionality I can't seem to find.

EDIT: And after reading through my own question again, I realized the business logic here wouldn't work... sorry for getting ahead of myself.

Comment: how have you created the table?is it a custom module you have created?

Comment: Yes, I have created the basic table (it has all of the columns accept the one I am asking for help with here) and yes this is in a custom module. I will post code tonight.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate things to take care here, one is dealing with the database table, you will find all the functions you need to use for CRUD operations on databases [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/dbtng_example!dbtng_example.module/group/dbtng_example/7).

The other issue is dealing with the table showed on the browser page, if you want to operate with tables your best bet (IMHO) is to use [Ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools), install  it and enable the Ctools Ajax example submodule, there you will find exactly what you want, a link that removes the file.

Hope this helps.